# Google Forms needing post processing writing to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

We're using a Google Form which writes to a Google Spreadsheet. I would like to do some post processing of the data as it enters the datasource.

I have the following code started. Is there a way to implicity obtain a reference to the active spreadsheet or do I need to modify it to have a hard reference to the id?

Is it possible to intercept a datastream and modify values before arriving at the Google Sheet?

```
function onFormSubmit(event) {
  // This function will be called everytime the form is submitted.
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1').getRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1').getLastRow(), 4).setBackground('#4287f5');
}
```

[image]

Comment: `getActiveSpreadsheet` does return the active spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You simply need to take advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events):

```
function onFormSubmit(event) {
 const ss = event.source;
 const as = ss.getActiveSheet();
 if (as.getName()=='Form Responses 1'){
    as.getRange(as.getLastRow(),4).setBackground('#4287f5');
 }
}
```

**Please Note:**

- There are two `onFormSubmit` triggers: one for [google sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) and one for [google forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1). In your case, since you want to edit something in the spreadsheet, it makes more sense to use the first one.
- Both are [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) which means that you need to install it either by a script or manually. To install it manually you can click on project's triggers, create a trigger, select `onFormSubmit` as the function and event type `On form submit`.

Comment: Regarding your second question, yes it is possible but it is better if you use a trigger on the submit form itself. I would advice you to post a new question regarding this so you can provide all the necessary details that required for the question to be answered.